# Angular MSAL unit test service calling another service

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, msal-angular

I am trying to test my service that calls another service.

I have `auth.service.ts` that contains login method that calls `MsalService.loginRedirect();`.

```
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import {
  MSAL_GUARD_CONFIG,
  MsalGuardConfiguration,
  MsalService,
} from '@azure/msal-angular';
import { RedirectRequest } from '@azure/msal-browser';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthService {
  constructor(
    @Inject(MSAL_GUARD_CONFIG) private msalGuardConfig: MsalGuardConfiguration,
    private msalService: MsalService
  ) {}

  login(): void {
    if (this.msalGuardConfig.authRequest) {
      this.msalService.loginRedirect({
        ...this.msalGuardConfig.authRequest,
        redirectStartPage: '/',
      } as RedirectRequest);
    } else {
      this.msalService.loginRedirect();
    }
  }
}
```

and a spec file

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { MsalAuthModule } from '@app/core/msal.module';

import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { MsalService } from '@azure/msal-angular';
import { MockService } from 'ng-mocks';

describe('AuthService', () => {
  let service: AuthService;

  const mockMsalService = MockService(MsalService, {
    loginRedirect: void {},
  });

  let msalServiceSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<MsalService>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [MsalAuthModule],
      providers: [{ provide: MsalService, useValue: mockMsalService }],
    });
    service = TestBed.inject(AuthService);
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should login', () => {
    spyOn(service, 'login'); // <- runs login method from service?

    msalServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj(mockMsalService, ['loginRedirect']); // <- creates spy?
    expect(msalServiceSpy).toHaveBeenCalled(); // <- test if msalService.login() is called
  });
});
```

But I am getting `Expected a spy` error.

[image]

Is my understanding correct?

1. Mock MsalService
2. Spy the mocked MsalService
3. run the login method using spyOn(service, 'login')
4. test the mocked MsalService' loginRedirect() if it is called using `toHaveBeenCalled()`

Then why its returning the error? Is my syntax wrong?

I am new to angular unit testing so I really appreciate your help :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there are a couple of issues with your testing approach.

unnecessary spyOn(service, 'login')

call the login method on the service

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { MsalAuthModule } from '@app/core/msal.module';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { MsalService, RedirectRequest } from '@azure/msal-angular';
import { MockService } from 'ng-mocks';

describe('AuthService', () => {
  let service: AuthService;
  let msalService: jasmine.SpyObj<MsalService>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    const mockMsalService = MockService(MsalService, ['loginRedirect']);
    
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [MsalAuthModule],
      providers: [{ provide: MsalService, useValue: mockMsalService }],
    });

    service = TestBed.inject(AuthService);
    msalService = TestBed.inject(MsalService) as jasmine.SpyObj<MsalService>;
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should login', () => {
    service.login();

    expect(msalService.loginRedirect).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```